# Uniqueness of the solution to a certain IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a strictly decreasing, continuous function with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$, and consider the following IVP:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=f(x(t))-y(t), \ \ \ y(0)=0$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f^{-1}(y(t))-x(t), \ \ \ x(0)=0$$
Since $f$ is continuous, this problem must have a solution. I am wondering, could a function $f$ be constructed such that multiple solutions exist?